# Wordpress get_transient returning false despite correct $key and transient in wp_options

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a gravity form utilizing an add-on upload field that post-submission does some background work to send a video file to YouTube, then return the YouTube video ID.

I am trying to set a transient value on gform submission that stores the post ID, so another hook related to this YouTube upload process can take the YouTube ID it gets, then update a custom field for the aforementioned post.

Setting the transient works and I can see it in wp_options, but when I try to get the transient, it continually comes back empty despite the key values being identical.

```
function action_prso_gform_youtube_uploader_pre_update_meta( $field_values, $this_data ) {
  //vars
  $gforms_entry_title = strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $this_data['gforms_entry'][1])));

  //Get new post id so we can update it's meta
  $transient_post_id = NULL;
  $key = 'adv_' . $gforms_entry_title;
  $transient_post_id = get_transient($key);

  //You have the post id, save the youtube id as post meta
  $yt_video_id = $field_values[6][0]['video_id'];
  update_post_meta( $transient_post_id, 'video_testimonial_youtube_data', $yt_video_id );
}
add_action( 'prso_gform_youtube_uploader_pre_update_meta', 'action_prso_gform_youtube_uploader_pre_update_meta', 10, 2 );

add_action("gform_after_submission_19", "submit_video_testimonial_from_submission", 5, 2);
function submit_video_testimonial_from_submission($entry, $form) {
  // Create a new post under the "video-testimonial" post-type
  $new_video_testimonal = array(
    'post_title' => ucwords($entry[1]),
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_type' => 'video-testimonial'
  );

  $gforms_entry_title = strtolower(preg_replace('/-+/', '-', preg_replace('/[^\wáéíóú]/', '-', $entry[1])));

  $theId = wp_insert_post($new_video_testimonal);

  // Now we add the meta to the custom fields
  $thePrefix = 'video_testimonial_';
  update_post_meta($theId, $thePrefix.'title', ucwords($entry[1]));
  update_post_meta($theId, $thePrefix.'description', ucwords($entry[2]));
  update_post_meta($theId, $thePrefix.'name', ucwords($entry[3]));
  update_post_meta($theId, $thePrefix.'location', ucwords($entry[5]));

  // Set a transient to pass post ID for YouTube api function
  set_transient('adv_'.$gforms_entry_title, $theId, 500);
}
```

I've set error_log on every field, including $transient_post_id and; it records nothing.

Comment: It would sure seem that $key isn't containing the correct key by the time it gets to the get_transient call, but I'm guessing you've tried error_log'ing that to be sure? I also assume there's more code we're not seeing, because it never seems to check if the transient is still set. Is it expected that these two functions will always be called within 500 seconds of each other?

Comment: error_log does show that the $keys are the same for set and get.

yes -- 10-15 minutes is more than enough time for the process of the video being sent to upload to take place.  I've found this takes as little as 20 seconds.